# Weird database issues

Tags: database, local.xml

I can't access my site... I've tried all manner of troubleshooting. details are definitely correct, i've downloaded a clean version of magento and pasted in a fresh local.xml

Is there anything else I can try to troubleshoot?

http://www.omni-drones.nl/

Comment: Please contact your hosting provider to get this solved.

Comment: I just checked the website its working, can you once try clearing browser cache

Comment: Welcome to Magento! Please check this [great debugging tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429)

Comment: Well, still not entirely sure what it was... hosting comoany said it wasn't db related (I am still convinced it was) so I downloaded a fresh copy of local.xml reentered all local.xml info, cleared var etc etc. then it reappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seams clean. You don't have access to your database for user `omnidrone`. Either the user does not exist or the password is wrong. Check `local.xml` for any tralling spaces or other chars.
Also clear the contents of folder `var/cache`.

Comment: This is what I did actually, passwords weren't wrong... so assuming a hosting error

Answer (score 0):

Your database username or password is incorrect. You will need to verify the information and re-enter to you app/etc/local.xml file